# EF POCO - Unable to infer a key for entity type?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a POCO class, mapping to a table that basically contain three primary keys as follow:

```
public class ContactProjectSite
    {
        public int ContactID { get; set; }
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public int SiteID { get; set; }

        public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
        public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the class that inherit the DbContext class, override the OnModelCreating method:

```
public class TLI : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ContactProjectSite> ContactsProjectSite { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ContactProjectSite>().MapSingleType(cps => new
        {
            cpcid = cps.ContactID,
            cppid = cps.ProjectID,
            cpsid = cps.SiteID
        }).ToTable(new StoreTableName("contacts_ps", "dbo"));
    }
}
```

However, when running this, I gets this error: **Unable to infer a key for entity type 'Library.Models.ContactProjectSite'. ** Any idea why?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you set the primary key in your EDMX? Does your EDMX Validate?

Comment: For some reason this has made me hungry for El Pollo Loco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the `[Key]` attribute to indicate which property is the primary key when EF can't figure it out from names/types.  I *think* you can apply it multiple times to create a composite key.

Comment: All those are foreign keys that points to other primary keys. Do I have to make sure the foreign key relationship are actually set on the tables? Thanks.